# Creating new android project in eclipse takes forever

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I have installed eclipse IDE with Android SDK already built in. When I try to create a new android project the wizard shows and I go through all the steps with no problem but on the last step when I click Finish the project takes forever to build. The wizard just stands there and I can't interact with it nor with the eclipse.

On the eclipse's status bar I can see memory usage and in the first two-three seconds after I click finish in the wizard, the memory usage is getting bigger but after two-three seconds it stops, and everything stops. But it is not a deadlock because after an hour or so I can see that the memory usage has increased by 1MB (only 1MB). By that rate it will take forever to create a project. I left it overnight and still it didn't finish.

(I have tried to increase eclipse's memory limit to 1024MB but it didn't help)

EDIT:

The CPU consumption by the eclipse (and javaw.exe) is low, around 1%.
My CPU is AMD A6-3400M, OS is Windows7 64bit, 4GB RAM.

Comment: Likely have a corrupted ADT or Eclipse install. Try downloading a new copy of both and try again. Creating an Android project should take seconds.

Comment: @tencent yes I have instaled new copy of eclipse with ADT built in (from the [Android SDK site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)), but still no change...

Comment: You could try re-installing your JVM. Have you tried non android projects in eclipse like creating a standard Java Project? If that works well then maybe your Android SDK install is bad?

Comment: @tencent hey, yes other projects in eclipse (like just java project) are working normal so it's likely problem with the SDK then... I'll try something else though, I'll install eclipse with Android SDK 32bit version, (the one I have is 64bit) and give it a try...

Comment: It works with 32bit!... The project created normally, it took it about 15sec xD. I'll use 32bit eclipse then...

Comment: Ahh yes, you should definitely use the 32bit JVM And 32bit Eclipse with Android development as Android is only 32bit capable.